# How to convert a String to int on assert

Tags: java, string, int, assert

Assert cannot be able to find value because it's expecting a String but an integer  is present instead. How can I be able to convert this String to an integer.

I tried using Integer.parseInt(number) but it is ignored.

Here's my code below

```
@Then("^User assert \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void userAssertAnd(String Qty, String Price)  {
    String Quantity = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='GEHR2AJDIL']/td[8]/div/input[@class='form-control']")).getText();
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals(Quantity, Qty);

    String modifierPrice = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='GEHR2AJDIL']/td[9]/div/input[@class='form-control GEHR2AJDHI']")).getText();
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals(modifierPrice, Price);
```

Error: expected:<> but was:<120>

Comment: `Price` seems to be `null` here.

Comment: Price is actually a value @Joey

Comment: 120 is quantity or price? from this "Error: expected:<> but was:<120>"

Comment: @AkhilMenon 120 is quantity and price is R 355.60

Answer (score 0):

So 120 is quantity, here quantity is defined as string.So you need to convert the quantity to String like this:

```
String Quantity = String.valueOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@class='GEHR2AJDIL']/td[8]/div/input[@class='form-control']")).getText());
```

Comment: I'm still getting error: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<> but was:<120>